# How to populate json in a dropdown with Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui

If I have the following json data, How can I populate `Bird_Name` in the dropdown list with semantic?

**Note:** I'm using react with es6.

```js
var birds = [
            {
                "ID": "001",
                "Bird_Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove"
            },
            {
                "ID": "002",
                "Bird_Name": "Bald Eagle"
            },
            {
                "ID": "003",
                "Bird_Name": "Cooper's Hawk"
            },
        ];
```

**Semantic dropdown**

```
            <Container>
                <Divider hidden />
                <Dropdown 
                placeholder='Select...' 
                selection
                search
                options={options}
                />
            </Container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is by mapping the `Bird_Name` fields as `text`, and assuming you want the `ID` as the value:

```
const options = birds.map(({ ID, Bird_Name }) => ({ value: ID, text: Bird_Name }))
```

Now you can pass the options into your `Dropdown` component

You can check out the codepen here: https://codepen.io/poda/pen/BYwZNB

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1. Change your data to be like the schema that dropdown accept
2. You can map your data to the `dropdown.item` and put it in the dropdown as a variable